# How to make it access database path relative in asp.net web.config file

Tags: asp.net

I am trying to change the path of my access database from an absolute path to a relative one in my web.config file. I have search on stack overflow and tried to use the suggestion they have had, but they didn't work. here is my current connection string:

```
<add name="2007 SoundAssist VER 1.0.5  05-12-2011 ConnectionString" connectionString="Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=&quot;C:\Users\Esfahanian\Dropbox\Anderson\ SoundAssist VER 1.0.5  05-12-2011.mdb&quot;" providerName="System.Data.OleDb"/>
```

Any help would be most excellent. Thank you guys for your time

Comment: You may have to specify path in code via call to `Server.MapPath`

Comment: What @YuriyGalanter said. This is especially important because it is not a good practice to store your database in your web site folder. It can potentially allow people to download the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare *partial* connection string in the Web.Config:

```
<add name="2007 SoundAssist VER 1.0.5  05-12-2011 ConnectionString" connectionString="Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" providerName="System.Data.OleDb"/>
```

And then in code augment it with something like this (this example is in VB)

```
Dim connectionString As String = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("2007 SoundAssist VER 1.0.5  05-12-2011 ConnectionString").ConnectionString & Server.MapPath("/your/application/path/SoundAssist VER 1.0.5  05-12-2011.mdb")
```

*UPDATE: C# Version*

```
string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["2007 SoundAssist VER 1.0.5  05-12-2011 ConnectionString"].ConnectionString + Server.MapPath("/your/application/path/SoundAssist VER 1.0.5  05-12-2011.mdb");
```

Comment: I am doing my project in c#, is there any way that you can show how to do the second part using c#?

Comment: I put this in <string connectionString=ConfigurationManager.ConnectionString["2007 SoundAssist VER 1.0.5  05-12-2011 ConnectionString"].ConnectionString + Server.MapPath("/Dropbox/Anderson/2007 SoundAssist VER 1.0.5  05-12-2011.mdb");></string>
What am i doing wrong exactly?

Comment: The solution consists of 2 parts: 1st - `<add name="2007 SoundAssist VER 1.0.5  05-12-2011 ConnectionString" connectionString="Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" providerName="System.Data.OleDb"/>` goes into your Web.Config ConnectionStrings section. 2nd - C# code - goes int your ASPX.CS file - this one without the tags, just variable declaration and assignment `string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["2007 SoundAssist VER 1.0.5  05-12-2011 ConnectionString"].ConnectionString + Server.MapPath("/your/application/path/SoundAssist VER 1.0.5  05-12-2011.mdb");`

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't work for me. But thank you for your help

Comment: Could u elaborate what exactly didn't work? If you found the other solution then good luck :)

Comment: After I put in my aspx.cs file, and run my website i get this error:CS0120: An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'System.Web.UI.Page.Server.get'

Comment: Server.get? Are you sure this code is inside of Web.Page code? If it's in some external CS code, try `HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath` instead of just `Server.MapPath`

Comment: OK now I am getting this error : DB_SEC_E_AUTH_FAILED(0x80040E4D).

Comment: That means the connection string is working. Please verify that path to MDB is correct (do not use path from my example)

Comment: Sorry for so many question but I am new to this, so I am bit confused by what path it wants cause I tried putting in these both C:/Users/Esfahanian/Dropbox/Anderson? 2007 Sound Assit.... (Which I know is wrong cause thats the absolute path) and I have tried this /Dropbox/Anderson 2007 Sound Assist... So what exactly am i doing wrong. Btw thank you so much for being so helpful

Comment: If your application root is "/" and folder you want to put your file is "/DropBox", then you should use `HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("Dropbox/SoundAssist VER 1.0.5 05-12-2011.mdb");`. Please try to put a breakpoint in code at that point and see if that function returns correct physical path to the file

Comment: No problem :) Glad it was successful at the end

Comment: The partial path in the second part of the connectionstring `/your/application/path/SoundAssist VER 1.0.5  05-12-2011.mdb` should not be hardcoded like this. It should also come from an `applicationSettings` value in your web.config.